# Reasoning through this probability problem

Tags: probability

Two men are chosen randomly from a group with **$n$** people. Some of those people have have a cat and some don't. Some are men and some are women. It is a given that the probability that $2$ chosen people being both men and having a cat is $\frac{39}{995}$.

Now, there's more information to this problem, but I believe this will suffice. The probability of being a men and owning a cat is $0.2$. What is the value of **$n$**, that is, how many people are there?

The answer lies in the solution to this equation and here's where I get stuck: $$0.2\cdot \frac{0.2n-1}{n-1}=\frac{39}{995}$$

I know how to solve the equation, I just don't know why it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ be the number of men with cats and let $N$ be the total number of people.

From what you said, we have that probability of a men with a cat being selected is:

$$\frac{m}{N} = 0.2$$

And the probability of selecting (I'm assuming without replacement) two men with cats is:

$$\frac{m(m-1)}{N(N-1)} = \frac{39}{995}$$

Can you solve it from here?